# MS-SQL and HierarchyID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, hierarchy

I have been using HierarchyID for the last 2 years in some of my tables for obvious purposes

And I have kept a Column (int) for the last node number
for example if I have these rows so the int column for number will be

```
| HierarchyID | Number |
| ----------- | ------ |
| /1/         | 1      |
| /1/5/       | 5      |
| /1/6/       | 6      |
| /2/         | 2      |
| /2/8/       | 8      |
| /2/9/       | 9      |
| /2/1/10/    | 10     |
```

I have tried to find a way, to extract the last node value without having to convert ToString() and break the string by the "/" char and going to the last item

Is there a better, maybe built-in, way to do it?

I'm using sql2019

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you ask that. But I built it within the SQL, again, the column is as HierarchyID

Comment: I mean, are you using hierarchyid methods (GetDescendant(), GetAncestor()) or some external app is generating a hiearchical string and then is parsed and inserted into the database?.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the HierarchyID methods